# calculating work experience with momentjs

Tags: datetime, momentjs

I am trying to figure out how to best calculate work experience using momentjs.

Let's say I have had the following jobs:

1. from december 15. 2013 - march 15 2013
2. from february 20. 2013 - june 1. 2013
3. from september 1 2013 - december 1 2013.

as you can see there is an overlap between job 1 and 2, and there is a gap between job 2 and 3.
The challenge is that i just can't calculate the difference between the start of job 1 and the end of job 3, since there is a gap between job 2 and job 3.
On the other hand I cannot just add the timediff for each job since there is an overlap between job 1 and job 2.

Any input on how to tackle this the best, is appreciated.

thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is unfortunately not solvable with moment.js. But I wrote a simple solution for you, using integers as `start` end `end` values:

```js
calc_duration = function(list) {

  // calculate the duration and add it to the list elements
  // when you are working with you need to adjust how x.duration
  // is retrieved
  list_with_duration = list.map( function(x){
    x.duration = x.end - x.start
    return x
  }).sort( function(a,b){
    return a.start > b.start
  });

  // sums all the durations together except for overlapping dates, there it
  // will only add the time span of the second date that exclusive of the
  // first date
  total_duration = list_with_duration.reduce( function(sum, curr, i, list){
    if (i == 0 || list[i-1].end < curr.start ) {
      return sum + curr.duration;
    } else if ( list[i-1].end > curr.end ) {
      return sum;
    } else {
      return sum + curr.end - list[i-1].end;
    }
  }, 0);

  return total_duration;

}


calc_duration([{start: 0, end: 10},{start: 5, end: 15},{start:20, end: 30}])
//returns 25

calc_duration([{start: 20, end: 30},{start: 5, end: 50},{start:0, end: 10}])
//returns 50
```